# ffmpeg pipe to generate h264 chunks from numpy array or bgr24 bytes

Tags: ffmpeg, python, video-conversion, video-streaming, h.264

is there a possibility if someone can help me with FFmpeg pipe to generate h264 chunks from NumPy array

This is what I am doing now:

process = (
ffmpeg
.input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgr24', s='{}x{}'.format(self._deeptwin.image_width, self._deeptwin.image_height))
.output(path, pix_fmt='yuv420p', vcodec='libx264', r=25)
.overwrite_output()
.run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)

```
for res in response:
    st = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f'{res.status} image {res.id} rendered at {datetime.datetime.now()}')
    img = np.frombuffer(res.image, dtype=np.uint8)
    img = img.reshape((int(self._deeptwin.image_height * 1.5), self._deeptwin.image_width))
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420)
    
    for frame in img:
        start = datetime.datetime.now()
        process.stdin.write(
            frame
            .astype(np.uint8)
            .tobytes()
        )
        end = datetime.datetime.now()
    stop = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(f'{res.id} conversion done at {stop-st}')
process.stdin.close()
process.wait()
```

`
What this is doing currently is generating an out.h264 file. It is fine and playing a correct video as well.

However, what I need to achieve: I want to generate chunks of h264 frames in the following way: 1.h264, 2.h264............n.h264

Any guidance would be really appreciated and helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume you want to create multiple .264 files. What is the condition when to end a .h264 chunk?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. You figured it correctly that I want multiple .264 files. It's for a streaming application. So, there is no such condition on when to stop apart from when the client stops getting these image bytes from the ML model. However, if such a condition is required, I can maybe read few chunks of let's say 25 images or 50 images.